# How to trigger a websocket message from outside websocket itself in fastapi?

Tags: python, websocket, fastapi

I have a connection Manager where I store active connections

```
class ConnectionManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.active_connections: Dict[str ,WebSocket] = {}

    async def connect(self, websocket: WebSocket, client_id: str):
        await websocket.accept()
        self.active_connections[client_id] = websocket

    def disconnect(self, websocket: WebSocket, client_id: str):
        self.active_connections.pop(client_id)

    async def update_progress(self,client_id: str, progress: int):
        websocket = self.active_connections.get(client_id)
        print(websocket)
        await websocket.send_text(f"progress: {progress}")
```

Then there's the websocket that the client sets up event listener to

```
@app.websocket("/ws/{client_id}")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, client_id: str):
    await manager.connect(websocket, client_id)
```

and the client will upload a file through a post request, I want that post request to trigger the websocket to send updates on the progress to the client.

```
@app.post("/upload/s3")
async def upload_to_s3(payload: Request):
    payload = await payload.json()
    data = payload.get("data")
    process = payload.get("process")
    client_id = payload.get("currentId") 
    flag = True
    try:
        # if process == "update_facebook_spend_cap":
        while flag:
            for i in range(1, 101):
                await asyncio.sleep(0.1)               
                progress = i
                print(progress)
                await manager.update_progress(client_id, progress)
                if progress == 100:
                    flag = False
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=123123, detail="sum wrong")
```

However I just keep getting error after error, too long to post here.
If i do the same logic but on the websocket itself it works, however if I try to use the method manager.update_progress() from outside of the websocket function it'll fail.

Is this doable at all?